# How can i get the user data from the following vue array?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

[The vue.js array output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iezom.png)

This is my vue array out put . i am able to get the length of the likes by using @{{post.like.length}} but i am unable to fetch the perticular data like @{{post.like.id}} or @{{post.like.user_id}}

Comment: Well, you need to iterate over the list to access the individual items (`length` is a property of the array, `id` is a property each element features). Can you show, what you already tried?

Comment: i have tried  @{{post.like[0].id}} but it is showing one array only not any other property .

Comment: You have not share any code and not any sample data

Comment: i have shared a screenshot of the vue root in inspect element .check it please

Comment: `post.like[0]` is the whole `like` object? also, shouldn't be `post.likes[0]` (with `s`)?

Comment: Let me check that

Answer (score 0):

To render the likes of a post within a template, use [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if). For example:

```
<li v-for="like in post.likes">
    Like ID: {{ like.id }}, 
    Post ID: {{ like.post_id }},
    User ID: {{ like.user_id }}
</li>
```

With plain JS, use [forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp):

```
post.likes.forEach(function (like) {
  // access like.post_id, like.id, ...
});
```

Comment: thanks sir . i think i got the answer from your answer